# VB.NET Picturebox image from url

Tags: vb.net, image

Im trying to load images from a url to a picturebox but I can't get it to work. The url of the page is "http://www.example.com/storage/image?12345" but the picture box doesnt load it. And here is the source code of a page where the image are on. This is the whole code of the webpage and it's using php code that i dont have access.

```
<html>
   <body>
       <img style = "-webkit-user-select: none" src = "http://www.example.com/storage/image?12345">
   </body>
</html>
```

My question now is how can i get it to work using the given url. But when I try to get image in other website like in google image. it was working fine. i hope someone can help me out of this. thnx

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using a desktop application. What you should do is to use WebClient to download the image as a byte array and then convert the byte array into a BitMap which you can assign to the PictureBox

Comment: but i dont want my application to download files. if it possible i want my picturebox to stream/load image from url. thx